# Opening javascript buttons in new window

Tags: html, forms

How would I go about making all these buttons open in a new window?

```
<form method="post" action="http://bloc.name/nnews.php">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-inverse"  name="newbreforms">+ QOL & approval</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-inverse" name="newbcement">+ Stability</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-inverse" name="newbmilitary">+ 5K troops</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-inverse" name="newbmoney">+ $600k</button>
<br />
<button class="btn btn-large btn-inverse" name="riotreforms" type="submit">+ Approval</button>
<button name="usaidtrain" class="btn btn-large btn-inverse" type="submit">+ Military training</button>
<button name="usaidair" class="btn btn-large btn-inverse" type="submit">+ Airforce</button>
<button name="usaidmoney" class="btn btn-large btn-inverse" type="submit">+ $400k</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you mean a dialog box inside the same page or in a new page?

Comment: I would like it to open in a new page

Comment: Open what in a new window?  The submitted form?

Comment: Do you want to open a new window with that html form/button?

Comment: Kindly be specific? Dont make us guess what u want

Answer (score 6):

Add `target="_blank"` to the form tag.

```
<form method="post" action="http://bloc.name/nnews.php" target="_blank">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add target='_blank' to the form.

`<form target="_blank"></form>`